# splitting json array in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting the response from ajax as json:

```
{"checkin_date":["2017-05-11","2017-05-18","2017-05-23","2017-05-25"]}
```

I need to separate these values in javascript like 2017-05-11, 2017-05-18, etc.

I tried split function in javascript but it failed. How do I achieve it?

I need the dates separately in a loop.

Comment: split into separate array ???Why?? What is the expected output

Comment: Wait, so you're trying to take an array inside an object, and turn it into another array? Can't you just access the array inside the object?

Comment: no i need that dates separately in a loop

Comment: Do you wanto loop over the array

Comment: yes need to display all dates in a loop

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript/36774966#36774966  . Also here you need to loop over obj.checkin_date

Comment: too much attention for so simple question. OP, please read some js doc, about datatypes in js, loops and JSON format.

Answer (score 2):

Parse the JSON string using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method and get the property which holds the array.

```
var dates = JSON.parse(respose_data).checkin_date
// or
var dates = JSON.parse(respose_data)['checkin_date']
```

---

If it's an object then directly access the property.

```
var dates = respose_data.checkin_date
// or
var dates = respose_data['checkin_date']
```

---

**UPDATE :** And now iterate over the array using [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or a simple for loop.

```
dates.forEach(function(v){
   console.log(v);
})

// or
for(var i = 0;dates.length < i; i++){
   console.log(dates[i]);
})
```

Comment: Not what the OP needs Pranav

Answer (score 1):

You just use method parse of JSON. After that, you receive array value for property "checkin_date". Just use it as normal array. See code below:

```js
var json = '{"checkin_date":["2017-05-11","2017-05-18","2017-05-23","2017-05-25"]}';
var result = JSON.parse(json);
var checkin_date = result['checkin_date'];
for(var i=0; i<checkin_date.length; i++){
  console.log(checkin_date[i]);
}
```

Comment: Did you "Run code snippet" above? It works normally.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple solution using arrow function:

```
const json = {"checkin_date":["2017-05-11","2017-05-18","2017-05-23","2017-05-25"]}

json.checkin_date.map((date) => date)
```

If you need it on pre-ES6 JavaScript, just do it like:

```
var json = {"checkin_date":["2017-05-11","2017-05-18","2017-05-23","2017-05-25"]}

json.checkin_date.map(function(date) { return date })
```

Both ways you will have returned all the dates from the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- Parse content of your request to a JavaScript object using `JSON.parse()`.
- Take property `checkin_date` which contains an Array with the list of dates.
- Loop the Array and do whatever you need which each date.

```js
let respose_data = '{"checkin_date":["2017-05-11","2017-05-18","2017-05-23","2017-05-25"]}';
let dates = JSON.parse(respose_data).checkin_date;
dates.forEach(date=> console.log(date))
```

More info on [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: tried but SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data error showing

Comment: double check that your JSON is correct and with no sytax error. You can paste your JSON result here http://jsoneditoronline.org/ and see if it validates.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to loop through each value as a date, you first need to convert the values. Take a look:

```js
var dates = {"checkin_date":["2017-05-11","2017-05-18","2017-05-23","2017-05-25"]};

dates
  .checkin_date
  .map(date => new Date(date)) // here you convert the string dates to values of type Date
  .forEach(date => console.log(date)) // here you loop through every Date and do whatever you want, in this case I just logged the output.
```